# Show $\frac1{(n(n+1))^m} =\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} a_{m,k}(-1)^k(\frac1{n^{m-k}}+(-1)^{m-k}\frac1{(n+1)^{m-k}}) $ where $a_{m, k} =\binom{ m-1+k}{k} $

Tags: binomial-coefficients, riemann-zeta, partial-fractions

The current
American Mathematical Monthly
 has the identity

$\frac1{(n(n+1))^3}
=6(\frac1{n}-\frac1{n+1})
-3(\frac1{n^2}+\frac1{(n+1)^2})
+(\frac1{n^3}-\frac1{(n+1)^3})
$

which is used to show that
$10-\pi^2
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{(n(n+1))^3}
$.

This led me to ask:

What about
$\frac1{(n(n+1))^m}
$?

Experimentation led to
this conjecture:

$\frac1{(n(n+1))^m}
=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} a_{m,k}(-1)^k(\frac1{n^{m-k}}+(-1)^{m-k}\frac1{(n+1)^{m-k}})
$
where
$a_{m, k}
=\binom{ m-1+k}{k}
=\binom{ m-1+k}{m-1},\\
$

and this is what I would like a proof of.

This has been verified
for $1 \le m \le 5$.

Note that this leads to
the following results:

If
$$s(m)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{(n(n+1))^m}
$$
then
$$s(m)
=(-1)^m2\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor m/2 \rfloor} a_{m,m-2k}\zeta(2k)-(-1)^m\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} a_{m,k}
$$
so that
$$s(2m)
=2a_{2m,0}\zeta(2m)+2\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} a_{2m,2m-2k}\zeta(2k)-\sum_{k=0}^{2m-1} a_{2m,k}
$$
and
$$s(2m+1)
=-2a_{2m+1,1}\zeta(2m)-2\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} a_{2m+1,2m-2k+1}\zeta(2k)
 +\sum_{k=0}^{2m} a_{2m+1,k}
$$

Too bad this shows nothing about zeta of odd parameter.

Comment: This is just the partial fraction decomposition $\frac{1}{n^m (n+1)^m} = \sum_{l=0}^{m-1}  \frac{\textstyle\frac{f^{(l)}(0)}{l!}}{ n^{m-l}}+ $ $\frac{\textstyle\frac{g^{(l)}(-1)}{l!} }{(n+1)^{m-l}}$ where $f(x) = (x+1)^{-m}, g(x) = x^{-m}$.